# drawing a nerve cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Can the next drawing be done? and if possible as a nice 3-d editable object that can be displayed part by part (as using visible<1> visible<2>).
[image]

That is the best I can do, which I am not satisfied with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% begin Nerve Cell2
\begin{minipage}[c]{1\textwidth}
\hskip 4cm
{
\tikz \shade[inner color=yellow, outer color=red] (0,0)circle(.5cm);
\vskip -.18cm
\hskip .86cm
\tikz % multiple lines, with rounded corners
\draw[thick,rounded corners=10pt, red, top color=red, bottom color=red, middle color=red!25]
(0,0)--(0,-1)--(3.5,-1)--(4.2,-.8)--(3.4,-1.12)--(4.2,-1.1)--(3.4,-1.22)--(4.2,-1.4)--(3.4,-1.34)--(4.2,-1.65)--(3.4,-1.45)--(-3.5,-1.45)--(-4.,-2)--(-3.54,-1.25)--(-4.,-.5)--(-3.5,-1)--(-.5,-1)--(-.5,0)--cycle;
\vskip -1.32cm
\hskip .1cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=10pt,ultra thick]
\shade[inner color=yellow, outer color=green] (.25,1.4)circle(.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip -.86cm
\hskip -1.78cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=10pt,ultra thick]
\shade[outer color=green, ,inner color=green!35] (-1.6,-.42)rectangle+(2,.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{minipage}
% end Nerve Cell2

\end{document}
```

[image: mytest]

Comment: Of course can be drawn, however for this some effort is necessary. What you do so far?

Comment: unfortunately, I did nothing. I designed this drawing in Corel presentation; and I would like to do it in Latex

Comment: If you did it in corel, you don't need to repeat in LaTeX. Just import it in beamer with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: I understand, that he like to have series of images which can be uncovered as talk progress. If I will have sparse time on evening I will try to prepare some basic (if in  meantime someone else will not do).

Comment: Thank you Zarko. Yes I would like to edit this drawing. I shifted from Corel to Latex, and I would like to draw and edit this drawing.

Comment: What do you mean by a '3-d editable object'? The image you have posted is not 3d. And why have you coloured bits in green if you want it red? Am I being overly suspicious in thinking you've copied the code from somewhere else and claimed it as your own work? Because I can't think of any other way you would come up with code for the second picture in an attempt to draw the first. I hope I have an overly suspicious mind because plagiarising other people's code is obnoxious.

Comment: @ cfr. Hello cfr, no this is my own work. I did it in Corel presentation, and now I am shifting to using tikz. I want it to look nice as a 3-d object if possible, which I do not know how to do. I am using it as a part of my presentation to teach dental students. Please refer to my question "drawing a complex object by incorporating shapes" which I am trying to make it as simple as possible so that it can be edited for further adding of other parts. Thank you.

Comment: Please refer to my question "drawing a complex object by incorporating shapes", both are parts of the same drawing I am trying to do.

Comment: "which I am not satisfied with" is not really specific. Can you please point out the things you like to improve in your image?

Comment: The ***code*** you posted isn't produced by Corel, surely? Unless it has rather surprising options....

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283313/drawing-a-complex-object-by-incorporating-shapes.

Comment: @cfr This is not a Corel code. This is what I could do in latex, which I need a more appropriate code to draw what I want to do in my original question.

Comment: But why would you make it `green` if you want `red` or `blue`? That's why I can't understand why you'd write *that* trying to draw *this*. And you haven't said what you mean by 3D. TikZ does not support real 3D editable objects or real 3D at all. You can at best fake 3D in 2D. That means that if, say, you want to adjust the viewing angle, you have to redo the code.

Comment: @cfr The green part is a cell beside that cell in red. If 3D is not possible, it is ok.  I was hoping that someone can show me how to do it.

Comment: But your target image contains no green.... It isn't clear what really the problem is or what you want to change since it seems unlikely that you would draw the second image trying to draw the first.

Comment: @cfr The green part is the same as the blue part in the target image. It is ok if tikz does not support 3D, nothing you can do to help me. Thank you.