# drawing a complex object by incorporating shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can shapes be incorporated into one drawing; as making the green rectangles appear as the red drawing, so no lines appear between them, and filling them as a one unit? and incorporating a circle into a series of lines to become one drawing, centered vertically to each other? Can text be added to different parts?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% begin incorporate shapes centred vertically

\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=8pt,ultra thick]
\draw[blue, outer color=green, ,inner color=green!35] (0,0)rectangle+(2.,.7);
\draw[blue, outer color=green, ,inner color=green!35,rotate=90] (0,-.6)rectangle+(4,.7);
\draw[blue, outer color=green, ,inner color=green!35] (-.1,3.3)rectangle+(2.,.9);
\draw[blue, outer color=green, ,inner color=green!35] (-.1,1.5)rectangle+(7.5,.8);
\draw[blue, outer color=green, ,inner color=green!35,rotate=90] (2,-4)rectangle+(1.5,.7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vskip 2cm

\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=8pt,ultra thick]
\draw[red, top color=red, bottom color=red, middle color=red!25]
(0,0)--(0,-1)--(3.5,-1)--(3.5,-1.45)--(-3.5,-1.45)--(-3.5,-2.5)--(-2.5,-2.5)--(-2.5,-3)--(-4,-3)--(-4.,2)--(-2.,2)--(-2.,1)--(-3.5,1)--(-3.5,-1)--(-.5,-1)--(-.5,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
% end incorporate shapes

\vskip 2cm

% begin Nerve Cell2
\begin{minipage}[c]{1\textwidth}
\hskip 4cm
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[blue, rounded corners=8pt,ultra thick]
\draw[inner color=yellow, outer color=red] (0,0)circle(.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip -.18cm
\hskip .88cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[blue, rounded corners=8pt,ultra thick]
\draw[top color=red, bottom color=red, middle color=red!25]
(0,0)--(0,-1)--(3.5,-1)--(4.2,-.8)--(3.4,-1.12)--(4.2,-1.1)--(3.4,-1.22)--(4.2,-1.4)--(3.4,-1.34)--(4.2,-1.65)--(3.5,-1.45)--(-3.5,-1.45)--(-4.,-2)--(-3.54,-1.25)--(-4.,-.5)--(-3.5,-1)--(-.5,-1)--(-.5,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{minipage}
% end Nerve Cell2

\end{document}
```

[image: incorporate shapes as a one drawing]

Comment: *Can* it be done? Yeah, probably. With hours of work. Perhaps you'd like to make a start and then the TikZ experts here can lend you a hand when you get stuck?

Comment: Hello  cfr  , I hope you are interested in my question. I appreciate very much your answers

Comment: _"Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document."_

Comment: @Hany, very nice attempt but it seems it belongs to your another question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283308/drawing-a-nerve-cell

Comment: @CroCo. Yes, they both are parts of the drawing I am trying to do.

Comment: Hmm, its quite old, but perhaps the `\unionclip` in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58559/combine-tikz-paths/58950#58950) helps?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you want to do this in TikZ? Why not use something like Inkscape which would, I imagine, make this much easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [Tom Bombadil's `\unionclip`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58950/) with [Zarko's drawings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283877/) in the following way. This is obviously just an example: it is up to you to develop the specific combinations you need.

It is generally easier to use relative, rather than absolute coordinates from the beginning when possible. In the case of a `pic` you might think this doesn't matter as they are always relative, in a sense. But, even then, the use of relative coordinates facilitates various kinds of flexibility, such as making it easier to combine code in different ways e.g. to make another `pic` or, as here, to specify two related `\clip`s. I've therefore made almost all of Zarko's coordinate's relative as opposed to absolute. Absolute coordinates are used only as anchor points for the clipping paths.

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=5pt]{standalone}
% from Tom Bombadil's answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58950/
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\newcommand{\unionclip}[3]{% number of clippings, clipping commands (connect with &), draw commands
  \newarray\temp%
  \readarray{temp}{#2}%
  \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}%
  { \begin{scope}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xt}{\x}%
      \temp(\xt)%
      #3%
    \end{scope}%
  }%
  \delarray\temp%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=1.2mm, thick]
  \unionclip{2}{% 
    % based on Zarko's answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283877/
    \clip
      (0,1.2) coordinate (a-north)-| ++(0.2,-1) -| ++(2.8,-.2) coordinate (a-east) |- ++(-6,-.2) |- ++(1,-1) |- ++(-1.4,-.4) -- ++(0,1.6) coordinate (a-west) |- ++(1.4,2.4) |- ++(-1,-.8) |- ++(2.8,-1.4) |- ++(.2,1);&
    \clip
      ([xshift=35mm]a-east) ++(0,1.2) coordinate (b-north) -| ++(.2,-1) -- ++(3.3,0) -- ++(.7,.4) coordinate (b-east above)  to [out=225, in=175,looseness=4] ++(0,-.45) to [out=195, in=165,looseness=6] ++(0,-.3) to [out=195, in=135,looseness=4] ++(0,-.45) coordinate (b-east below)  -- ++(-.7,.4) -- ++(-3.5,0) coordinate (b-south)       -- ++(-3.5,0) -- ++(-.5,-0.4) coordinate (b-west below) to  [out=45, in=-45,looseness=1.3] ++(0,1.2) coordinate (b-west above)  -- ++(.5,-.4) -| ++(3.3,1) -- cycle;
  }{%
    \fill [top color=red, bottom color=red, middle color=red!25]
    (-4,-2) rectangle (15,2.5);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: combo-solution]

However, you cannot use `pic`s directly in `\clip`s, which is why I've just copied the relevant paths into the `\clip` commands here. `\clip` is restricted to simpler things than constructions such as `\path` and `\draw` and so on, so it isn't as straightforward as simply turning a `\pic` into a `\clip` directly.

[And, as I mentioned before, `pic` is partially broken in recent versions of PGF/TikZ, especially concerning naming. Since this broke some time ago and the bug has persisted, I assume that the regression is due to other changes and that it is not a simple fix. If so, it will presumably stay broken for the foreseeable future. However, this is pure speculation on my part. I just wouldn't count on its being fixed any time soon.]

Note that even if these were `node`s rather than `pic`s, you could not use them directly to clip. Clipping wants closed paths. Nor could you join them in any straightforward way. Again, unless you use a uniform fill etc. - but you can do that with `pic`s, too, of course. Just use the same colour fill for each and don't draw the border so that they join continuously.

The main reason to use `\unionclip` is that you can apply a shading across the entire combined shape so that the colour changes smoothly. At least, that's the only reason I can think of here. Transparency would be another reason or fading and so on.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I appreciate very much your effort and time spent for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

I understood, that you like to form set of building blocks of for complex images. For this job seems to be handy small pictures `\pic`, which you defined in `\tikzset and than use in complex image. Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,shapes}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{mynevro/.style = {
nerve1/.pic = {\path[draw=red, rounded corners=1.2mm, thick,
            top color=red, bottom color=red, middle color=red!25]
        ( 0.0,1.2) coordinate (-north)-| (0.2,0.2) -|
        ( 3.0,0.0) coordinate (-east) |- (-3,-0.2) |- (-2,-1.2) |-
        (-3.4,-1.6) --
        (-3.4,0.0) coordinate (-west) |- (-2,2.4)
        |- (-3,1.6) |- (-0.2,0.2) |- (0,1.2);
                },
nerve2/.pic = {\path[draw=blue, rounded corners=1.2mm, thick,
            top color=orange, bottom color=orange, middle color=orange!25]
        ( 0.0, 1.2) coordinate (-north)       -| ( 0.2,0.2) -- (3.5, 0.2) --
        ( 4.2, 0.6) coordinate (-east above)  to [out=225, in=175,looseness=4]
        ( 4.2, 0.15) to [out=195, in=165,looseness=6]
        ( 4.2,-0.15) to [out=195, in=135,looseness=4]
        ( 4.2,-0.6) coordinate (-east below)  -- ( 3.5,-0.2) --
        ( 0.0,-0.2) coordinate (-south)       -- (-3.5,-0.2) --
        (-4.0,-0.6) coordinate (-west below) to  [out=45, in=-45,looseness=1.3]
        (-4.0, 0.6) coordinate (-west above)  -- (-3.5, 0.2) -| (-0.2, 1.2) --
        cycle;%
        \coordinate (-west) at (-3.8,0);
        \coordinate (-east) at ( 3.8,0);

               },
nerve3/.style = {circle,minimum size=7mm, draw=black,
            inner color=yellow, outer color=red,
            node contents={~}
                },
                            }
         }% end of tikzset
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mynevro]
\pic (A) {nerve1};
    \node[above] at (A-north) {north};
    \node[right] at (A-east)  {east};
    \node[left]  at (A-west)  {west};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[mynevro,
    node distance = 0mm,
    points/.style = {circle, inner sep=1pt, fill=red},
         pin edge = black
                    ]
\pic (A) {nerve2};
\node[points,pin=45:north, above=of A-north] {};
%
\node[points,pin=45:east above,  above right=of A-east above] {};
\node[points,pin= 0:east,        right=of A-east] {};
\node[points,pin=315:east below, below right=of A-east below] {};
%
\node[points,pin=315:south, below=of A-south] {};
%
\node[points,pin=240:west below, below left=of A-west below] {};
\node[points,pin=180:west,       right=of A-west] {};
\node[points,pin=135:west above, below right=of A-west above] {};
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[mynevro,
    node distance = 0mm,
                    ]
\pic (A) {nerve1};
\pic (B) [right=42mm of A-east] {nerve2};
\node[nerve3,above=of A-north];
%
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

With designed small picture you can almost unlimited compose complex picture. In their positioning in picture you need to take a care width of pic.  As they are defined as in above MWE, its anchor is at inner coordinate (0,0).

To `pic` you can add nodes with text etc relative to coordinates defined for each `\pic`.  This is demonstrated in first two images, where are designates anchors of pic by nodes with anchor names (the first picture) and by nodes with pins with anchor names.

**Addendum:** The positioning of small pictures is tricky. In this a drawer had to keep in mind that above `\pic` has origin at internal coordinate `(0,0)`, which is 12 mm below anchor `north` and 37 mm right from anchor `west` (see definition of `nerve2`). Consequently, that `nerve2` can follows `nerve1` without gap between them, their position should be defined (relatively) as:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[mynevro,
    node distance = 0mm,
                    ]
\pic (A) {nerve1};
\pic (B) [right=37mm of A-east] {nerve2};% <-- 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In this case the picture is:

[image]

As help in composing of nerves into complex images serves the first two images in the first pictures.

There is another problem with `pic`. As cfr mentioned in her comment: " *... the pic naming is broken and has been for a while. That is, some of the syntax which did work and should work and is in the manual does not work at the moment and hasn't for some time. ...*"

Comment: You might want to mention that, although the code you are using does work, the `pic` naming is broken and has been for a while. That is, some of the syntax which did work and should work and is in the manual does not work at the moment and hasn't for some time. (For example, the seagull code from the manual does not work.)

Comment: I'm not sure this actually answers the question because the question isn't very clear. (I read it as asking something else, but you could easily be correct in your reading.)

Comment: I have similar doubt, is my answer is what OP looking for, on the end I think that a new aspect on his problem can help him to formulate new, more clear question or in the best case even gives framework for his further work. Regarding `\pic` naming, alas you are right. With `\pic` I have another problems to: its positioning in picture is not straightforward. As you can see from my third example, I need to consider distance from left border of `\pic` to its inner coordinate (0,0), what is very annoying. I hope that in next release of TikZ some of those problem will be solved.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you Zarko. I will try to understand and apply your answer, since I am new to tikz.

Comment: @Zarko Hello Zarko. Thank you very much for your answer.
I am very sorry for the delay. I had some personal problems that prevented me from trying your precious answer. It is very helpful.
Just one comment, in your mini picture, there were text attached to the drawing; but when applying your code, no text was displayed.
Again thank you very much, and I am very sorry for the delay

Comment: @Hany, meanwhile I forgot on this my answer ... now I see, that my MWE not belong to presented picture, probably it is one of more my performed tests. I corrected this now.

Comment: @Zarko, Thank you very much. I applied your correction, and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Zarko, Hello Zarko; if I may bother you once more. In your very helpful answer, the part of the drawing labelled "nerve3", could it be incorporated with "nerve1" so there will be no boundary between them to make them appear as if they are a one structure? Thank you.

Comment: @Hany Only if you define a new `pic`. Of course, if you filled them with a solid colour, you could effectively join them seamlessly. But there's no automatic way to make 2 shapes into one that I know of. The `\unionclip` method is probably the best approach. If you draw them separately, you can't then join them, so to speak.

Comment: @cfr Thank you. How can I use the \unionclip in the above example to incorporate nerve3 with nerve1.